# Sequilize - Delete ManyToMany Associations

Tags: sequelize.js, many-to-many

I'm using Sequilize to program a common Student - Course relational database in NodeJS.
The 2 Models are associated through the automatically generated relational table `student_course`:

```
Course.belongsToMany(Student, {
  through: "student_course",
});

Student.belongsToMany(Course, {
  through: "student_course",
});
```

In order to update the courses associated to a Student I am used to delete all the entries in the association table `where: {studentId: "id of the selected Student"}`, and insert the new associations that the user posts.

Looking at the Documentation I can see that

> When an association is defined between two models, the instances of those models gain special methods to interact with their associated counterparts [source](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances)

and one of these methods listed under the paragraph **"Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, { through: Baz })"** is the `fooInstance.removeBars()` which I thought would be the perfect choice to my needs.

But `student.removeCourses()` generates the following SQL query:

```sql
DELETE FROM `student_course` WHERE `studentId` = 6 AND `courseId` IN (NULL)
```

and because of `courseId IN (NULL)` condition the query is not working, i.e. nothing is deleted. It works if I specify the `courseId` like for example `student.removeCourses([1,2,3])`.

But how do I delete all the entries associated to one students? Should I query all the Courses and fill an array with their id?
Please let me know if I should post some example code.

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem as you

Comment: Mark the answer of @DinoStray as correct, to help more people know the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all associated courses of one student, use student.setCourses([]) instead